# How to read values from a textfile then pass them to a function

Tags: linux, python-3.5

I am trying to read some values in a text file that I have called status.txt and then input these values to the function. Since the Function accepts bytes only , I need to convert it to bytes but I am getting junk. Here is the part of the code I am referring to:

```
import time
import datetime
import serial
import os

# public variables
sensors = []  # list of sensor readings
wait = True
sensor_count = 10 # the zero based count of sensors


def pwr_solenoid(solenoid0=solenoid[0], solenoid1=solenoid[1], solenoid2=solenoid[2], solenoid3=solenoid[3]):
    # Defaults are for low signal values

    # compile output
    output = '9{solenoid0}{solenoid1}{solenoid2}{solenoid3}'.encode()

    with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=9600) as ser:
        print("created connection to '/dev/ttyACM0'\n")
        print("going to send:\t'{}'".format(output))
        ser.write(output)
        ser.reset_output_buffer()

        # for testing to console
        print("Value sent to the uC:\t'{}'".format(output.decode()))

        # ***** READ from UART *****
```

and here is the code from the main function

```
def main():
    os.system("clear")

    # create the list of sensors (hardwired to 10 at the moment)

    # make sure that the list of sensor values is clear
    sensors.clear()

    for i in range(0, sensor_count):
        sensors.append(SensorReading(sensorID=i, humidity=0))

    print("Enter solenoid values in form of 1/0 (1 == HIGH, 0 == LOW) or 'exit' to exit\n")
    print('\n')
    print("default value will remain '0000' until altered...\n")
    print("Note, after altered values are input, it will wait for input from UART||USB\n")
    print('\n')

    solenoid = '0000'
    solenoid_raw = open("status.txt")
    solenoid = str(solenoid_raw)
    pwr_solenoid(solenoid0=solenoid[0], solenoid1=solenoid[1], solenoid2=solenoid[2], solenoid3=solenoid[3])
```

I am trying to read the numbers from the text file I am assuming it will be string , pass that to the function pwr_solenoid , then it's supposed to append that value to 9 and turn it to bytes and write over the serial port but it is not writing the right thing, any help would be appreciated.
Neil.

Comment: What is the format of `status.txt`? Can you include some example data in your question?

Comment: the format of the text file is just 4 numbers that are either 0 or 1
right now it is 1001 . I am trying to read this , append 9 to it and write it over the serial port , so what I want to write in the serial port would be for example '91001' and I want everytime the text file gets updated to read that and write that over the serial port